# How to correctly write xml document with spaces and new lines inside using CDATA?

Tags: xml, cdata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CodeCases>
  <Case1>
    <CodeText>
      <![CDATA[
for(var i=0;  i;10;i++) {
      var x;
}
]]>
    </CodeText>
  </Case1>
</CodeCases>
```

This is the code I'm using, however, when I open in browser, it doesn't read the new lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it important to you to be able to open it in a browser? Does it work when you open it in a _program_?

Comment: The code in the middle is JavaScript.
What do you mean open it in a program? I'll need to read it through XML reader or something similar via C#

Answer (score 1):

With CDATA, your new lines are preserved. The issue in your case isn't that. If you look at the source of generated html file (In firefox, via `View` -> `Page Source` or `CTRL`+`U`) you'll see that the new lines are preserved in the text. I've just tried your CDATA section by myself (via some XSLT processing).

What happened in your case is that the browser just doesn't care about the raw new lines, and multiple white-space added in html files.

To maintain the formatting of the text, you need to wrap the content with the [`white-space` css property](http://xhtml.com/en/css/reference/white-space/) set to `pre`

ie, the HTML content will be something like,

```
<div style="white-space:pre;">
for(var i=0;  i;10;i++) {
      var x;
}
</div>
```

Usual way of maintaining line breaks is adding `<br>` tags. But it doesn't really apply here.